How to get texts after <br> tags
The Website
<p style="margin:1em auto; padding:0 1em; max-width:700px;">
<b>
Lamborghini</b>
 <br> 
<img style="width:300px" src="https://i0.wp.com/www.car-revs-daily.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/2011-Lamborghini-EGOISTA-22.jpg">
 <br> 
2013 Lamborghini Egoista
</p>

I want to extract the name of the random car (2013 Lamborghini Egoista).
I have tried:
String text= (String) jsExecutor.executeScript("document.querySelector('#output-container p').innerText;");

System.out.println(text);

,but it didn't work:

org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText')


I think you need to switch to the iframe first. I can see the website has iframe with XPATH //*[@id="output"]/iframe

Here is an example using the JavaScript code, and you can try to simulate the steps in Selenium:
// get the container element first
const containerELe = document.querySelector("#output-container");
// get the br (second br in the container)
const brElement = containELe.querySelector('br:nth-of-type(2)');
// get the node after the br
const nameNode = brElement.nextSibling;
// get text content
const name = nameNode.textContent.trim();


I'm using Java.

Selenium is just a way to simulate browser operation and you can even execute js in Selenium. So what you expect is the exact code, right ?

I found this solution:
driver.switchTo().frame(xpath("//*[@id=\"output\"]/iframe"));
String text= (String) jsExecutor.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#output-container p br:nth-of-type(2)').nextSibling.textContent");
System.out.println(text);

Thanks to @Nevemore,and @Pramesh  for the help
